# Bug in TIdIMAP4.ListMailBoxes?

Tags: delphi, indy10, delphi-10.2-tokyo

When I execute this command on a client's Lotus Notes server, I get lines returned looking like this:

```
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "\\" Folder\Subfolder 1
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "\\" Folder\Subfolder 2
```

In the resulting list, this is stored as:

```
[0] LIST
[1] \HasNoChildren
[2] \
[3] Folder\Subfolder
[4] 1
```

As I put this in a TreeView, I end up with:

```
- 1
|
- 2
|
- Folder
  |
  - Subfolder
```

My questions:

1. is the IMAP server's response valid according to the protocol?
2. how can I change the Notes config so it outputs the correct data (provided the client is willing to change it)?
3. Is this a bug?
4. And if so, how can I work around it?

I see there are two "failing" procedures: `InternalParseListResult` and `ParseIntoBrackettedQuotedAndUnquotedParts`.

Shouldn't `ParseIntoBrackettedQuotedAndUnquotedParts` simply regard everything after the delimiter as a Folder path?

`InternalParseListResult` doesn't check index 2 as Delimiter, instead it takes the one to last entry and takes the first character of that. In the example, the delimiter would become 'F'. It also decides that the last index is the folder name, so the folder ends up as '1' or '2'. Shouldn't it take the delimiter from `LSlRetrieve[2]` and regard `LSlRetrieve[3]` and higher as the folder name?

As all of these functions and procedures aren't virtual, I cannot create a descendant to reimplement the behavior. I can change Indy's code and have it revert back with the next update, so I am not looking to go that route.

When I run the command on our MS Outlook server, everything works as expected, as that returns lines like:

```
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Folder.Subfolder 1"
* LIST (\HasNoChildren) "." "INBOX.Folder.Subfolder 2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the IMAP Server's response valid according to the protocol?

As near as I can tell, yes.

> how can I change the Notes config so it outputs the correct data (provided the client is willing to change it)

You don't.

> Is this a bug?

Looks like it, yes.  I have opened a ticket in Indy's issue tracker:

https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/issues/329

> And if so, how can I work around it?

You could alter Indy's source code and recompile it. Which, as you already noted, will have to be applied each time Indy is updated.

The alternative would be to use detour hooks to redirect the failing functions to your own replacement functions. They don't need to be virtual to be detoured.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I'll discuss this with my team and decide whether to change the code or wait for a new INDY version

Comment: Hi Remy, is there an idea on when this will be fixed? That will edcide whether we go and change the code or not.

Comment: @DDi I do not have an ETA on a fix. It will likely be awhile, as I don't have time (or a functional compiler environment) to work on it any time soon. I would suggest moving forward with an alternative plan, and just make sure it can be turned off when a fix is released eventually.

Comment: thanks then I will make my own fix. Would it be possible to submit my chagnes to the code base? At least it would lighten the load by one bug, lol.

Comment: @DDi yes, you can submit a [pull request](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pulls) on Indy's GitHub site, or just send me the changes privately.